# Creating a day of year column overriding the leap day in a leap year

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, for-loop

I have a large database of climate variables - daily values of temp, humidity etc. I have a timestamp column %Y%m%d. I have removed leap days, as I need uniform 365 days for each of my years. I want to add a new column called 'day_of_year' with 1 to 365 for each year for as many years as I have in my database. How can I accomplish this in python, any pointers, please?

If I use the day of year function from pandas, I get 59 for feb 28 and get 61 for Mar 1. Is there a way to override the leap year, as I have dropped the leap day and get 60 for Mar 1?

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas' day of year function, but instead of giving it the real timestamp, e.g. `"2022-11-27"`, give it `"2021-" + timestamp[-5:]`. This will give you the altered number as if the timestamp was not a leap year.